# One-parameter Weibull distribution has unique MLE

Tags: probability, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

> Say we have i.i.d. random variables $X_1,\cdots, X_n$ with the one-parameter Weibull distribution specified below: $$f(x\mid\lambda)=\lambda x^{\lambda-1}\exp(-x^{\lambda})$$ where $\lambda > 0$ and $x > 0$ with $\lambda$ is unknown. We wish to show there is a unique MLE.

I figured the likelihood function is:

$$L(\lambda\mid x_i)=\prod_{i=1}^n \lambda x_i^{\lambda-1}\exp(-x_i^{\lambda})$$

which would make the log-likelihood function:

$$\ell(\lambda\mid x_i) = n\log(\lambda) + (\lambda-1)\sum_{i=1}^{n}\log(x_{i}) - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^{\lambda} $$

Our MLE will then satisfy the following equation (derivative of the above wrt $\lambda$):

$$ 0 = \frac{n}{\lambda} + \sum_{i=1}^n \log(x_i) - \sum_{i=1}^n \log(x_i)x_i^{\lambda}$$

This equation looks pretty unfriendly to solve in terms of $\lambda$. Is there something I'm missing somewhere earlier that can show the value of $\lambda$ must be unique?

Comment: Isn´t the derivative of $-x_i^{\lambda}$ w.r.t. $\lambda$ equal to $-\ln(x_i)\cdot x_i^{\lambda}$?

Comment: @callculus I believe so -- I changed the sign outside the summation to account for that -- am I totally missing something?

Comment: Take the result I´ve written. If you want, you can try to get rid of the leading minus sign. But it will not simplify anything.

Comment: I don´t know why you have accepted the answer. In my opinion you both have the wrong derivative.

Comment: @callculus hey there -- yep. I've edited my post accordingly. thanks for hte catch

Comment: You still have a negative sign at $\log(x_i)x_i^{\color{red}-\lambda}$

Comment: If your $\ell$ function can be shown to be strictly concave, and $\ell\to -\infty$ as $\lambda\to 0$ or $\to\infty$, you don't have to worry about solving the normal equation to get your result.

Comment: @kimchilover that's an awesome tip, I think I just figured it out. Thank you very much!